# External access tomcat amazon ec2 (windows 2016 server)

Tags: tomcat, amazon-ec2, dns, window

I have an amazon ec2 windows instance, and I have an application running on tomcat (port 8080).
I can not access the application by public dns from another computer.
I have disabled windows firewall, and I have released the http port in amazon's inboud rules.
What else do I need to set up?

Comment: What type of "networking" are you using (classic/VPC/etc.) for that instance. Can you ping the IP? Can you ssh to the box?

Comment: Did you set your SecurityGroup access properly?

Comment: PIng dont have response.